# ¿Cual es el numero mas elegido?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Empezando desde el pricipio el codigo trata sobre un juego de lanzar un dado hasta obtener un dado igual al de la casa. Si esto sucede se obtiene una recompensa de forma contraria se te quitara lo que apostaste asi hasta que te quedes si dinero para apostar o la casa se quede sin dinero gracias a las recompensas que te dieron.
Mi duda es la siguiente como podria poner en el apartado de la estadisticas(Este apartado se encuentra antes de cerrar main) ¿el número elegido más frecuente, menos frecuente y la cantidad de veces que salió cada número?.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <time.h>

  char name[20];
  int casa=150, jugador=25 , valor=0, lanzado=0; 
  int c, monto, dados, a,  b,  v;   
  int d=2+rand()%10;

  int rango_monto(){
  scanf("%d",&monto);
  }

  int recompensas(){
        if(c<=3){
       switch(c){
    case 1:
        monto*=1;   
        break;
    case 2:
       monto*=1.4;
       break;
    case 3:
       monto*=1.15;  
       break;
 }
 printf("\nEl dinero de la casa es de: %d\n",casa-=monto);
       printf("\nsu recompensa es de: %d\n\n", b=monto);
   (v+=b);
   (a+=monto);
 }else{
    printf("\nEl dinero de la casa es de: %d\n",casa);
    printf("\nle quedan: %d para seguir apostando\n\n", jugador-=monto);
    (v+=b);
    (a+=monto);
 }
}
int main(){
srand(time(NULL));

//nombre

printf("digame su nombre:\n");
 scanf("%s",&name);
 system("cls");

//dado

while(casa>0 && jugador>0){
       printf("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t%s tiene un monto de: %d\n",name,jugador);
       printf("ingrese un numero del 2 al 12:\n");
        scanf("%d",&dados);

//rango y monto

      if(dados>1 && dados<13){
          printf("ingrese su monto a apostar:\n");
           scanf("%d",&monto);
          
//Fuera del rango
     
while(monto>jugador || monto<=valor){
      rango_monto();
}
      
//veces que se tiro el dado

while(d!=dados){
       d=2+rand()%10;
       (c++);
}
recompensas();
(lanzado++);
system("pause");
system("cls");
 }
}
if(casa<=0){
   printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tVICTORIA");
}if(jugador<=0){
   printf("\t\t\t\t\t\tPERDISTE\n");  
}
printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t  %cResumen de partida%c\n", 91, 93);
printf("\n             El dado se lanzo: %d",lanzado);
printf("\t\t\t\t  Monto usado: %d\n", a);
printf("\n             Ganancias: %d pesos\n\n             ",v);
system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de lograr esto seria usando un array de la clase `vector`, una para tu dados y otra para el de la casa, luego como tu mismo dices debes aplicar conceptos de estadiscas como es el caso de la frecuencia relativa,etc
Un vector se comporta de la siguiente manera:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
//creacion de los arrays dinamicos
 vector<int>casa;
 vector<int>jugador;

 int dado1=5;
 int dado2=3;
 //insercion de datos
 casa.push_back(dado2);
 jugador.push_back(dado1);

 //recuperacion de datos
 for(int i=0;i<jugador.size();i++){
  cout<<jugador[i]<<endl;
  cout<<casa[i]<<endl;
 }
}
```